# Blank "data:" screen when using Selenium x Python x Chromium on Linux32

Tags: python, linux, selenium, web-scraping

I am working on a script that uses Python, Selenium (Chromium) using a Raspberry Pi 3.

When I execute the code, Chromium opens but keep stuck at a blank page named "data:".

Python version: 3.9.2
Selenium version: 4.1.3
Chromium version: 98.0.4758.106 (32 bits)
Chromedriver version: 98.0.4758.106

Any hints?

The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.minimize_window()

linkCompleto = "http://133.2.102.252:9999/simpleDesk"
driver.get(linkCompleto)
locationFirstBar = '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]'
locationUpperLimit = '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]'
locationLowerLimit = '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]'

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, locationFirstBar))
    )

    elemFirstBar = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locationFirstBar)
    elemUpperLimit = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locationUpperLimit)
    elemLowerLimit = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locationLowerLimit)

    ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(elemFirstBar, elemUpperLimit).perform()
    time.sleep(5)
    ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(elemFirstBar, elemLowerLimit).perform()    
    
except Exception as error:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
    print("Error!")
```

Comment: The link doesn't work. Is it a webserver you have off right now?